# Is there a good library for accessing HBase from Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, stargate

I spent some time looking around, and all I could find is Jython. It's an option, but is there something that could be used in a more pythonesque (simpler) way?

Comment: Also see HappyBase: http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [thrift python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/hbase-thrift/) but the project seems dead.
I'd go with starting [HBase REST server](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest), and then using python standard libraries to access that RESTful web service.

Comment: Stargate works out just fine, though it looks like there is no Python library that would wrap the Stargate calls in Python calls, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Stargate link that is mentioned with this answer seems to be not working any more

Comment: thanks @focode. updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Stargate is still in the contrib part of the Hbase project while ThriftServer is maintained in core(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift).
Grab the HBase.thrift file from the repository and run

`thrift --gen py HBase.thrift` on it, shove the contents into wherever, and startup a thrift server.
Stargate is very very slow. The HBase thrift still has some work to be done on it, however it is still being actively worked on

A couple of places to get started

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi

Comment: Stargate seems to be an integral part of HBase now.
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I'm trying to get something started at http://github.com/hammer/pyhbase. Totally a hack right now but will be polishing it over the next few weeks. I link to the Mozilla client that I started from.

Answer (score 1):

Also go through https://github.com/tousif/Hwrapper wrapper for the Hbase REST api.